# running and debugging locally 2 Azure function with visual studio code

Tags: azure, debugging, .net-core, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I use Visual Studio Code to develop and debug locally .net core azure functions.

I am successfully able to run one instance of vs code and the Azure function locally, but I am not able to run 2 different Azure functions locally mainly because I am not able to decide the port used to expose the azure function (7071).

I have found how to do it with Visual Studio 2019, but nothing for Visual Studio Code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port is defined in the local settings file, all you have to do is change one of the functions to a different port number:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "<language worker>",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<connection-string>",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "<connection-string>",
    "MyBindingConnection": "<binding-connection-string>",
    "AzureWebJobs.HttpExample.Disabled": "true"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": false
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLConnectionString": "<sqlclient-connection-string>"
  }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=csharp#local-settings-file